# How to pass an object parameter via react-router-dom navigate

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `useNavigate` to navigate to another page. I need to pass an instance of an interface as a parameter when navigate to another page. Is there anyway to pass an interface instance as parameter?

The interface I want to pass as a paramemter:

```
export interface Api {
  apiDescription: string;
  apiName: string;
  documentId: string;
}
```

The code:

```
const { api, refresh } = props;
const navigate = useNavigate();
return (
    <div className="view-button-block">
      <Button
        size="small"
        sx={{ color: "#000000DE", bgcolor: "#D9D9D6" }}
        onClick={() => navigate("/managementUi/viewApi", { state: api })}
      >
        View
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
```

I want to pass api as a parameter when navigate to route `"/managementUi/viewApi"`.

In viewApi.tsx the component I want to navigate to:

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Api } from '../../../common/Api.types';

const ViewApi = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.state);
  const api: Api = location.state;
  return (
    <div>
      {location.state.apiName}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Update: I passed api as a state in `navigate()`. However, in the component I navigate to, when I try to read the `apiName` field from it, it has error for `location.state` that "Object is of type 'unknown'". What's the correct way to read `apiName` from `location.state`?

If I try to assign state to a declaration of api, it will has error "type unknown is not assignable to type Api"

Comment: Presuming it's JSON/string serializable you should be able to pass it in route state. Have you tried that? See [mcve].

Comment: Why does the title talk about passing a Java object? Do you mean JavaScript? Because those are two very different languages.

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry, typed wrong word. I removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will recast the `location.state` ***as*** an object with the `Api` interface.

Example:

```
import { Api } from '../../../common/Api.types';

...

const ViewApi = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const api = location.state as Api;

  console.log(api);
  return (
    <div>
      <ViewHeader apiName={api.apiName} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks! it casts the type to Api now. But I didn't add {}. I used const api = location.state as Api instead. If I add {}, it will has error the type Api has no property named 'api'

Comment: @HenryBai Oh, right, sorry, that's because it's `{ state: api }` instead of `{ state: { api } }` when passed. Sorry for any confusion that may've caused. Thanks for catching that.